# Incorrect jQuery element width calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

Having a simple **html** code

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="headerBox">
    <div id="headerText">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with **css** styles

```
div#header {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
div#headerBox {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 10px double gray;
}
div#headerText {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and **jQuery** (2.x edge)

```
function resize(win) {
  var size;
  var w = $('#headerBox').width();
  $('#headerText').html('');
  $('#headerBox').css('font-size', 1 + 'px');
  $('#headerText').html(
    "width of <span style=\"font-size:2em;\">headerBox</span> element is " + w + "px");
  while ($('#headerText').width() <= w) {
    size = parseInt($('#headerBox').css('font-size').replace(/\D+$/, ''), 10);
    $('#headerBox').css('font-size', (size + 1) + 'px');
  }
  $('#headerBox').css('font-size', size + 'px');
}

$(window).resize(function(e){
  resize(this)
});

resize(window);
```

all together accessible via **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5rkq/)**,

I experience **incorrect jQuery element width calculation**. When you access the above fiddle, you see that `headerText` element is too wide. There should be same right padding as is on left side, text should be centered. Once you **resize** the **Result** window (in the fiddle), text is adjusted as supposed to.

Question is **WHY** there is incorrect calculation on the very first time?

It seems that `var w = $('#headerBox').width();` is incorrect calculated. **WHY?**

---

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you wanted outerWidth() instead? http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth

Comment: The jsFiddle displays correctly for me in Firefox.

Comment: @A.Wolff - I am using Chrome 31.0.1650.63m and it does not display it correctly

Comment: strange, i'm using same chrome version

Comment: @A.Wolff - close it, open again and then resize the **Result** window in the fiddle - you see no difference?

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ no, i don't see any difference

Comment: @A.Wolff - I have updated my question with an image that shows my experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Found the problem:

Due to `padding: 1em;` for **headerBox**, width of this element changes with change of `font-size`.

So in `while` loop I need to work with up-to-date information, not the one I stored at the beginning.

Therefore

```
var w = $('#headerBox').width();
...
while ($('#headerText').width() <= w) {
  ...
}
```

needs to be changed to

```
while ($('#headerText').width() <= $('#headerBox').width()) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `.width` doesn't include the padding of #headerbox. Use `.outerWidth` to get correct width.

```
var w = $('#headerBox').outerWidth();
```

Comment: -1 :: This is not an answer to my problem. Sure `.width()` does not include padding. I know that. I don't want padding to be included in the calculation.